# Trying to read a function from external file

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys I'm trying to clean up my form file a bit by adding external classes, but I came across an issue. It's saying that I'm not returning a value and I will get a null exception.

Here is the function:

```
    Public Function writeData()
    Dim writeFile As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("C:\Users\Nick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + frmLogin.txtCUser.Text)
    writeFile.WriteLine("User: " + frmLogin.txtCUser.Text) ' user
    writeFile.WriteLine("Pass: " + frmLogin.txtCPass.Text) ' pass
    writeFile.WriteLine("E-mail: " + frmLogin.txtEmail.Text) ' e-mail
    writeFile.WriteLine("Securite Question 1: " + frmLogin.ComboBox1.Text)
    writeFile.WriteLine("-------------------")
    writeFile.Close()
End Function
```

How can I return any kind of value here when all I am doing is writing data?

Edit:

Calling this when the button is cliked:

```
Dim userData As WriteUserData
    userData.writeData()
```

But it says userData is being used before it has been assigned a value.

Comment: Is userData a class file or Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your calling code to:

```
Dim userData As New WriteUserData
userData.writeData()
```

I'm guessing WriteUserData is a class, and you weren't instantiating the form before using it. The New keyword will create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just not return anything? Use `Sub` instead of `Function`:

```
Public Sub WriteData()
    (...)
End Sub
```

**Edit due to Edit**

Where is `WriteData` declared? Is it in the own `Form` or is it in another class?

If this method is in the own form that you are handling the button click, you should only write in your event handler Sub:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Me.writeData()
End Sub
```

Otherwise @Mike's answer should solve your issue.

Comment: Then when I assign it in the form class it says it's been used before it has been assigned a value.

Comment: Edit your question and post the code that is generating this warning. I guess (cannot go further than that) that you are assigning the 'result' of `writeData` to some variable, whereas you should only call it.

Comment: I'm calling it when the button is clicked:        Dim userData As WriteUserData
        userData.writeData()

Comment: It should be only: `userData.writeData()`